App-specific folders can be accessed without any 3rd-party app or root. Bug in Android 14?
I was trying to access my /obb and /data folders in my Samsung Galaxy M33 5G, but because of restrictions in Android 14, I was not allowed to do so, somehow I found out this.
I checked that whenever you update your Google Play system update, your Files app gets updated, I uninstalled the update and I got it in the apps screen, and I could finally access these restricted folders without any 3rd-party applications or something.
Video demonstration on Google Drive.
I found many solutions on YouTube, but each of them involved 3rd party apps.
Is it a bug that I can access them?

I just tried on Galaxy M12 (Android 13), and uninstalling the updates of the Files app reverting it to t_frc_doc_330543000, minimum Android 10, targeting Android 13. Maybe that's related (I don't remember how storage permission works since Android 10)

The key here is the fact that you reverted back to original version, which I think still targets Android 13. For backwards compatibility, Android doesn't apply all restrictions until the app targets the Android level the restriction was introduced.
So when you update Files to the version that targets Android 14, restriction gets applied.
This is not a bug per-se, just Android's approach to not breaking older apps that already had that permission.
All apps updated after August 31st, 2024 will have to target Android 14, so all new/updated apps (outside system apps, preloaded on your phone) will be prevented from accessing data folders on external storage.

Ya , maybe after android 15 , this time it will be resolved

It's not a function of Android version, but a function of application itself. Once the apps migrate the ability to access those directories will be phased out.

if what you said is true. Then what i infer from your text is that , if the files app is again updated back to the android 14 version , then i will be hidden again and the obb and data folders will not be accessible again .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1My9Bk8fvLjPRAiFKkCaZIcf943hq3MA2/view?usp=drivesdk

@SuTech AFAIR, the Files app was hidden from the app launcher in the latest version.

Okhay if thats the case i shall close this question...
